# How can I get object at certain index position from Promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a method that returns a Promise of tuple that includes an array of regions and the count (before filtering) from the server.

```
getMany(getManyRegionsQuery: GetManyRegionsQuery): Promise<[Region[], number]>
```

I have a variable where I am only interested in the regions.

```
regions: Promise<Region[]>;
```

Is it possible to get just the regions array of the Promise tuple?

Something like this (which obviously does not work)

```
this.regions = this.regionsStore.getMany(new GetManyRegionsQuery())[0];
```

Can I in some way tell the compiler that I only want the object at index position 0 from the Promise?

Comment: You need to wait for the result of the promise (with `.then()` or `await`) before accessing its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `then`:

```
this.regionsStore.getMany(new GetManyRegionsQuery())
    .then(([regions,]) => regions)
```

Or equivalent:

```
this.regionsStore.getMany(new GetManyRegionsQuery())
    .then(result => result[0])
```